# Translating a Java Server Page to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, jsp, session, .aspxauth

I am trying to run a simple password validator. I have already written it in JSP, and it works. I am a beginner in C# and ASP.NET, and wish to practice/learn by writing it in C#. As a beginner, I am running into some problems and was hoping for some help.

What I had originally worked well. It's a workaround which is bad practice - but good for learning Java and JSP. It's just using a POP server as a workaround to do user authentication - silly, but good to learn!

What I have at the moment is this class, which I believe should work, stored in a .aspx file which my form uses as the "action".

```
class POPServer
{
    static Boolean hasLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        const bool isValid;
        using (var client = new TcpClient("host.hosty.com", 110))
        using (var stream = client.GetStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("USER " + username );
            writer.WriteLine("PASS " + password );
            const string response = reader.ReadLine();
            isValid = response[ 0 ] == '+';
            writer.WriteLine("quit\n");
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

So I connect to the host storing the username and password and verify against this form :

```
<form action="POPServer.aspx" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login Form</legend>
    <label for="teachername">Username:
      <input type="text" name="teachername" id="teachername" value="" />
    </label>
    <label for="teacherpass">Password:
      <input type="password" name="teacherpass" id="teacherpass" value="" />
    </label>
    <label for="teacherremember">
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="teacherremember" id="teacherremember" checked="checked" />
      Remember me</label>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="teacherlogin" id="teacherlogin" value="Login" />
      &nbsp;
      <input type="reset" name="teacherreset" id="teacherreset" value="Reset" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

What I am wondering is :

Is the "form" of my code correct - is it correct to store my C# in an ASPX file and run it as required when the user attempts to log in? I can't find any information about this and I am assuming I need a structure like JSP where you would run :

```
if ( request.hasParameter( "Submit" ) )
{
    if ( POPServer.hasLogin( request.getParameter( "username" ), request.getParameter( "username" ) ) ) {
        response.location( "loginPage.aspx" );
    }
}
```

How do you store session data so after the user is authenticated, the "login page" is displayed and the user is permanently logged in rather than just brought to a link and then forgotten?

Comment: I'm using web pages with WebMatrix at the moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two diifferent approaches to coding ASP.NET, [Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973868.aspx) and [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). With ASP.NET Web Forms, which is what you're using, you can do code in the .aspx, however, usually code is placed in a code-behind named for the language being used, i.e. .aspx.cs or .aspx.vb.

The code-behind contains a class associated with the page. This class contains events that correspond to the page loading, button clicks, etc. ASP.NET supports a number of built-in controls that are specified using an asp: prefix, i.e. `<asp:Label runat="server" ID="MyLabel" Text="My label text"/>`. Labels and other elements can then be referred to by their IDs in the code-behind, i.e. `MyLabel.Text = "My different label text";`.

ASP.NET suports a collection called [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) in which you can store information that persists for the duration of the user's session.

I should point out though that ASP.NET has a security model based on providers and [login controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) that is integrated and provides a good deal more control over security behavior than the approach you're taking here. You should see the [Walkthrough: Creating an ASP.NET Web Site with Basic User Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184050.aspx) on MSDN.

I'd also highly recommend getting [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us) if you don't have it already. There are time-limited trial editions of the full product available. There are also free versions with a lesser feature set called [Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express) editions.

Good luck and I hope you enjoy learning this.